# Bash script AWS S3 bucket delete all the files using their names contaning

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to remove only the files which are ONLY older than 5 days according to the file name containing "DITN1_" and "DITS1_" time using a bash script within the AWS S3 Bucket but the issue is all the files i'm trying to delete looks like as follows:

DITN1_2016.12.01_373,
DITS1_2012.10.10_141,
DITN1_2016.12.01_3732,
DITS1_2012.10.10_1412

if someone can help me out with the code would be nice.

thanks in advance

Comment: This is not a code writing service. What did you try so far? Post your code! What happened when you ran it? What did you expect to happen instead? What specifically are you having problems with?
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

You can use aws cli command for deleting stuff using the bash script as follows

```
aws s3 rm s3://mybucket/ --recursive --include "mybucket/DITN1*"
```

However it does not support timestamp

For details see [aws S3 cli](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/rm.html)

Answer (score 1):

Is it important to use the name of the objects instead of metadata? You could get a list of objects in the bucket using the s3api:

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket example --no-paginate # this last option will avoid pagination, don't use it if you have thousands of objects
```

Adding

```
--query Contents[]
```

Will give you back the contents of every object, including a LastModified section, which will tell you when the object was last modified, for example "2016-12-16T13:56:23.000Z".

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/list-objects.html

You could change this timestamp to epoch using

```
date "+%s" -d "put the timestamp here"
```

And compare it with the current time - 5 days.

OR if you really want to delete objects based on name, you could loop over the keys like this:

```
for key in $(aws s3api list-objects --bucket example --no-paginate --query Contents[].Key)
```

And add logic to determine the date. Something like this might work, judging by your examples:

```
key_without_prefix=${key#*_}
key_without_suffix=${key_without_prefix%_*}
```

Then you have your date, which you can compare with the current time - 5 days.

Comment: thanks for telling me that but if possible please provides the possible code to get this done;

Comment: Thanks for telling me that but if possible please provides the possible code to get this done; as of now here are my two s3 buckets which i'm trying to delete all the objects which are older than 5 days and if the objects names containing "DITN1_" and "DITS1_" within the object names. `if [ "$EC2_REGION" = "us-west-2" ]; then BUCKET=vz-app-nts-ivav-qa-vz-app-nts-ivav-ditn1-s3bucket-s3u‌​ca5imooh for key in $(aws s3api list-objects --bucket BUCKET --no-paginate --query Contents[].Key) else BUCKET=vz-app-nts-ivav-dev-vz-ivav-nts-1991-dev-s3bucket-11o‌​f49nc4qhem fi`

Comment: I forget to include i'm trying to automate this functionality so daily it will remove all the objects which are older than 5 days and the objects names containing "DITN1_" and "DITS1_"